# Making Sub Lists Based on Lengths of Items

Tags: python, list, iteration

I want to split a list I have of 48 different lengths into a new list for each length of the item. I could do something like

```
for item in list:
    if len(item) == 1:
         len1list.append(item)
    if len(item) == 2:
         len2list.append(item)
```

etc etc but that would require 48 if statements, just wondering whether there was a more Pythonic way, using less lines of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to categorize your list based on its items length. So you can sort based on length and group them.You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for grouping the sub lists (or any iterable object):

```
>>> l=[[1],[3,4],[5],[6,7,8],[4,0],[2],[5,6,7]]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l,key=len),key=len)]
[[[1], [5], [2]], [[3, 4], [4, 0]], [[6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7]]]
```

There is some notes here :

- If you don' t want to do operations like indexing or other operations on list, you don't need to convert the result to list (as i have done in above answer) you can let the result to be as a generator that is pretty much efficient for long lists.
- If you want more performance in run time you can use dictionaries that use hash-table for storing their data which searching and inserting data has O(1) in them. @junnytony suggested a good way with `defaultdict`. you can also use `dict.setdefault` method :

  ```
  d={}
  for i in main_list:
      d.setdefault(len(i),[]).append(i)

  print d.values()
  ```

Comment: This works! Thanks for the quick response, but due to the vast amount (5x10^80 values to be exact) of data that needs to be processed I've decided to just cut it into chunks using simple numbers ([1:2]), as going through with for statements required a fair amount of time.

Comment: @dimethylarginine You're welcome! pls checkout the edit for more explanations!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `defaultdict` of lists. This is a dictionary that is initialized with a list for each key, so you can just append your items of different lengths to the appropriate list using the lengths of items as keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict
items_by_length = defaultdict(list)

for item in orig_list:
    items_by_length[len(item)].append(item)

grouped_list = list(items_by_length.values())
```

Comment: Haha, your code is _almost_ perfect (cf. my answer). Add some explanation, fix the name `list`, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: There!  14 sec difference :)